# How to combine yield with retry loops while preserving original context?

Tags: ruby

```rb
require_relative 'config/environment'

HTTP_ERRORS = [
  RestClient::Exception
]

module API
  class Client
    def initialize
      @client = RawClient.new
    end

    def search(params = {})
      call { @client.search(params) }
    end

    def call
      raise 'No block specified' unless block_given?

      loop do # Keep retrying on error
        begin
          return yield
        rescue *HTTP_ERRORS => e
          puts "#{e.response&.request.url}"
          sleep 5
        end
      end
    end
  end

  class RawClient
    BASE_URL = 'https://www.google.com'

    def search(params = {})
      go "search/#{params.delete(:query)}", params
    end

    private

    def go(path, params = {})
      RestClient.get(BASE_URL + '/' + path, params: params)
    end
  end
end

API::Client.new.search(query: 'tulips', per_page: 10)
```

Will output

```
https://www.google.com/search/tulips?per_page=10  # First time
https://www.google.com/search/?per_page=10        # On retry
```

I thought I was being clever here: have a flexible and unified way to pass parameters (ie. `search(query: 'tulips', per_page: 10)`) and let the client implementation figure out what goes into the url itself (ie. `query`) and what should be passed as GET parameters (ie. `per_page`).

But the `query` param is lost from the `params` after the first retry, because the hash is passed by reference and delete makes a permanent change to it. The second time `yield` is called, it apparently preserves the context and `params` won't have the deleted `query` anymore in it.

What would be an elegant way to solve this? Doing `call { @client.search(params.dup) }` seems a bit excessive.

Comment: I tend to shy away from modifying arguments, too many unexpected side effects. I think `params.dup` is the right way to go but I'd do it in `RawClient#search` since that's the thing that wants to modify `params`.

Comment: @muistooshort that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!